# using ckeditor in symfony3

Tags: php, symfony

I try to use ckeditor in symfony3, I successfully installed it but get an error when I try to us it in my form as described in tutorial (https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/IvoryCKEditorBundle/index.html):

```
$builder->add('content', CKEditorType::class);
```

but that produces this error:

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Ivory\CKEditorBundle\Form\Type\CKEditorType::__construct() must be an
>   instance of Ivory\CKEditorBundle\Model\ConfigManagerInterface, none
>   given

it looks like, there is a problem because a FormType should not demand params in its constructor, am I wrong?

Comment: That's seems be a bug in IvoryCKEditorBundle.

Comment: @felipsmartins It's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error and solved it by adding CKEditorBundle to AppKernel.
This was stated in the comments of [CountZero's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1559880/countzero) answer. You can find IvoryCKEditorBundle installation notes [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/IvoryCKEditorBundle/installation.html).

```
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            new Ivory\CKEditorBundle\IvoryCKEditorBundle(),
            // ...
        );

        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no bugs in IvoryCKEditorBundle. If you provide your composer.json, results of commands `bin/console debug:container` and `bin/console config IvoryCKEditorBundle` it'll really help me to give you more precise answer.

> it looks like, there is a problem because a FormType should not demand params in its constructor, am I wrong?

You are wrong, CKEditorType may demand params in its constructor, and it does so in the current version.
There's something wrong with file `vendor/egeloen/ckeditor-bundle/Resources/config/form.xml`
It should configure (provide) service dependencies for CKEditorBundle, but it doesn't.

I would try to update composer, clear cache and debug service container configuration for this bundle, it should look like this:

```
⇒  composer update
⇒  bin/console cache:clear
⇒  bin/console debug:container|grep ivory      
  ivory_ck_editor.config_manager                                       Ivory\CKEditorBundle\Model\ConfigManager                                                    
  ivory_ck_editor.form.type                                            Ivory\CKEditorBundle\Form\Type\CKEditorType                                                 
  ivory_ck_editor.plugin_manager                                       Ivory\CKEditorBundle\Model\PluginManager                                                    
  ivory_ck_editor.renderer                                             Ivory\CKEditorBundle\Renderer\CKEditorRenderer                                              
  ivory_ck_editor.styles_set_manager                                   Ivory\CKEditorBundle\Model\StylesSetManager                                                 
  ivory_ck_editor.template_manager                                     Ivory\CKEditorBundle\Model\TemplateManager                                                  
  ivory_ck_editor.twig_extension                                       Ivory\CKEditorBundle\Twig\CKEditorExtension
```

Comment: Yeah, for me it looks like the OP has forgotten to include the CKEditorBundle to `AppKernel`

Comment: @mblaettermann you are right!  I checked it again, I didn't forget it, but changed the appkernel in another project, doh. Thx. Btw, I like this sentence: "There are no bugs in IvoryCKEditorBundle." :)

Comment: If one of you make this an answer (to check the appkernel) I will mark it as solution